# How to delete Ubuntu's hidden or trash files and folders (like .trash-1000) on Windows volumes, from Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

Previously I used have Ubuntu on my laptop, but currently I am using Windows 8.

I found `.trash-1000` file appearing in my drive. I knew that this is due to deleting few files while using Ubuntu.

How to delete that file in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3):

If a trash folder is created in Ubuntu on a volume that Windows can read from and write to, then you can delete it in Windows like any other folder.

That is, in Windows Explorer (the Windows file browser, not to be confused with the related Internet Explorer, a web browser):

1. Select the file(s) and/or folder(s) you want to permanently delete. In this case, that's the `.trash-1000` folder. (This is almost certainly a folder rather than a file. But if it were a file, this would still work.)
2. Make sure no *other* files or folders are selected, to avoid accidentally deleting something you don't want to delete.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

This will delete the selected items. It does *not* send them to the Recycle Bin first. So be careful! It's still *sometimes* possible to recover data deleted in this way--that is, this is not a *secure* delete. But it's *often* not possible to recover data deleted in this way.

[image: permanently deleting a trash folder from Ubuntu, in Windows]

That procedure **also works in Ubuntu**. In almost any file browser (such as Nautilus, the default file browser; or Thunar, Xubuntu's file browser; or PCManFM, Lubuntu's file browser), you can select items and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete them without first sending them to the trash. (But if you're in Ubuntu and wish to clear out *the contents* of a trash folder, you can typically just empty the trash.)

[image: permanently deleting a trash folder from Ubuntu, in Ubuntu]

In Ubuntu, files and folders whose names start with a `.` are hidden by default. In just about any file browser in Ubuntu, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files. Pressing it again hides them again. As an alternative to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut key combination, you may instead check (and uncheck) View > Show Hidden Files in the menu bar.

[image: showing hidden files in Ubuntu]

You can see `.trash-1000` in Windows, suggesting either that Windows is *not* treating it as a hidden file (Windows doesn't automatically do this for "dotfiles") or that you have Windows Explorer configured to show hidden files by default.

However, if you know (or believe) a hidden file is present but you can't see it in Windows, you can tell Windows Explorer to show hidden files. One way to do this, which will apply inside all folders, is to open Folder Options in the Control Panel, click the View tab, and under *Advanced settings*, select the "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" option button under "Hidden files and folders." (Then click Apply and OK.)

[image: showing hidden files in Windows]

Note that you do *not* generally have to uncheck the *separate* "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" box, and you shouldn't uncheck that unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on Eliah Kagan's answer:

- The `1000` in `.trash-1000` is the [UID](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html) of the user who deleted the files. 1000 is the typical UID of the user who installed the system in Debian and Ubuntu.
- You can, and probably should, browse the `.trash-1000/files` directory to look for files you may want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

These .Trash folders appear in any operating system used when files are deleted using Linux to delete.  All our computers run both Windows & Linux, accessing the same Archive, Data & Storage drives, regardless of operating system.

If deleting is difficult, try renaming the folder to a simple name, then try again.  On a Linux system, try emptying the Trash Bin.  On any Windows system, sometimes Shot-Del sometimes works.  Otherwise third-part "shredder" applications sometimes work.  In Windows, the best luck we consistently have is the freeware version of "Advanced SystemCare".