# I can't delete the .Trash-1000 folder

Tags: usb, 15.04, trash

I try to delete the .Trash-1000 folder of my USB stick however I can't do it. I get the following error and when I click on delete it just crashes and does nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/437035/how-to-delete-ubuntus-hidden-or-trash-files-and-folders-like-trash-1000-on-w).

Comment: @Mitch Those questions have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: @Mitch Aren't you going to undo the duplicate tag? I clearly stated that my question has nothing to do with the ones you pointed at.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/716100/edit) your question adding information to which why these questions have nothing to do with your problem.  Because you asked how to delete the .Trash-1000 folder, and both questions address that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mitch I don't ask how can I delete it. I share an error that happens when I try to delete the folder. Waiting an analysis or explanation.

Comment: Your question title says "I can't delete the .Trash-1000 folder".  The first line of your question says" try to delete the .Trash-1000 folder".  That tells me that you're trying to delete the folder.  If that's not your intention, then as I said, please edit your question, and state exactly what you want done.  The duplicate, and the other link that I added in the comment, both address the same error message that you're getting.  Thanks